# How can I clear a text box of enter or newline (html / javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a simple online chat room using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. Anyway, I recently added a feature to automatically submit the message upon the enter key being pressed. But whenever I do this, the value of the text box has a new line in it. 
Here's an example... 
**Before submitting a message**

```
document.getElementById("send").value;
```

"" 
**After submitting a message**

```
document.getElementById("send").value;
```

" 
" 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Are you preventing the default action of the enter key? It may be adding a new line into your text box

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove them

```
var UserInput = document.getElementById("send").value
UserInput = UserInput.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
```

The replace function checks the string for returns and new lines using a regular expression, when it finds one, it replaces it with "", or nothing.

Hope this helps you